# Clearing values from a row and simulate a click on it

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-events

I'm adding a row dynamically to a table and I need to do 2 things after it:

1. clear the values
2. simulate a click on a newly created link (the link is in one of the cells).

Here is the code that adds the row to the table (which is working fine):

```
var row = $('.records_table tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
row.insertAfter('.records_table tbody>tr:last');
```

My row html code looks like this:

```
<tr class=​"odd">​
   <td class=​"name">​name_0</td>​
   <td class=​"type">​type_0​</td>​
   <td class=​"value">​value_0</td>​
   <td class=​"edit">​
       <a href=​"edit" class=​"edit">​edit​</a>​
   </td>​
</tr>​
```

So, my first question: How can I clear the values name_0, type_0 and value_0?

Now, the second question. I need to simulate a click on a the link "edit" in order to trigger an event linked to the selector "a.edit" (this event is being correctly triggered for the pre-existing edit links in other rows that are loaded with the page).
I'm able to get the button as `var editbtn = $("td:last", row)`. I'm able to hide the link doing `editbtn.hide()`, but doing `editbtn.click()` is not triggering the event as expected.

The handler that should get the click is: `$(document).on('click', 'a.edit', function(e) {`, which again is working on the other links in other rows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Q2: the handler will only fire on items in the DOM. If the row is added after loading the page, you need to reset the handler or add a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can traverse it like this

```
var row = $('.records_table tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
row.insertAfter('.records_table tbody>tr:last');
$('.records_table tbody>tr:last') // gets last tr
    .find('td') // gets all td
    .not('.edit') // not the td with class=edit
    .text('') // make all text empty
    .end() // go back to first selector
    .find('a.edit').click(); // find anchor within tr and trigger click
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59hyL/1/

If you want the click on the last td instead of anchor.. you can do it like this

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var row = $('.records_table tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
    row.insertAfter('.records_table tbody>tr:last');
    $('.records_table tbody>tr:last')
        .find('td')
        .not('.edit')
        .text('');        
    $('tbody td:last').click();
});

$('.records_table').on('click', 'td.edit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("anchor number " + $('td.edit').index(this) + 'clicked');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hEP5q/

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will answer both of your questions:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Add row</button>
<table class="records_table">
    <thead><tr><th>Head</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>*</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
//simple function to repeat a string num times
String.prototype.repeat = function( num )
{
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
}


var i = 2;
var char = '*';

var lastRowSelector = '.records_table tbody tr:last';
//click handler for the cell
$(lastRowSelector + ' td').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
    var lastRow = $(lastRowSelector);
    //clone the row (note that handler will be cloned as well)
    var newRow = lastRow.clone(true);
    //obtain the only 'td' cell in the row
    var cell = newRow.find('td');
    //clear text of the cell by replacing it with new text. You could call cell.text('') to just clear it
    cell.text(char.repeat(i++));
    //insert the row to the end of the table
    newRow.insertAfter(lastRowSelector);
    //simulate click
    newRow.click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pr5jr/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can find the last appendrow using `:last`

```
var row = $('.records_table tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
row.insertAfter('.records_table tbody>tr:last');
// Recently added row..
var recentRow = $('.records_table tbody>tr:last');

recentRow.find('td').each(function(){
    $(this).text('');  // Will clear the values..
})
```

Comment: your method to clear the values worked, but I already have access to the last row. Any ideas of how to answer the 2nd question? Someone else voted your answer down.

Comment: Don't use  editbtn = $("td:last", row)  .. because it points to the row from which it is cloned...  Use editbtn = $("td:last", recentRow) instead

Comment: Looks like you are delegating the event right.. So instead of clone(true)   clone() should be sufficient